# How to copy all jsons files from folder1 and folder2 into third?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a lot of json in two folders name of json which need to be added together are same.
They must be added like folder1/1.json folder2/2.json. Because current script just add them by name.

```
folder1/
   1.json
   2.json

folder2/
   1.json
   2.json

folder3/
  1.json(info from folder1 and folder2)
```

My script which add them by names, but need to add by folders

```
import json
    
    with open("folder1") as fin1:
        data1 = json.load(fin1)
    with open("folder2") as fin2:
        data2 = json.load(fin2)
    new_json = [data1,data2]
    with open("folder3", "w") as fin3:
        json.dump(new_json, fin3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer based on requirements.

```py
import os
import json

f1_name = 'folder_1'
f2_name = 'folder_2'
f3_name = 'folder_3'
f1_files = os.listdir(f1_name)
f2_files = os.listdir(f2_name)

for f in f1_files:
    if f.endswith('.json') and f in f2_files:
        with open('%s/%s' % (f1_name, f), 'r') as fo:
            tmp_f1 = json.load(fo)
        with open('%s/%s' % (f2_name, f), 'r') as fo:
            tmp_f2 = json.load(fo)
        
        tmp_f3 = {**tmp_f1, **tmp_f2}
        with open('%s/%s' % (f3_name, f), 'w') as fo:
            json.dump(tmp_f3, fo)
```

Comment: I need to add info from jsons too, before copy them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 'folder1', 'folder2' and 'folder3' are the paths to the directories in question, then:

```
from pathlib import Path
import json

for path in Path('folder1').glob('*.json'):
    dir, file_name = path.parent, path.name
    with path.open() as f1, open('folder2/' + file_name) as f2, open('folder3/' + file_name, 'w') as f3:
        data1 = json.load(f1)
        data2 = json.load(f2)
        # do processing
        json.dump(new_json, f3)
```

You may have to add an `encoding` argument (e.g. `encoding='utf-8'`) on your `open` calls depending on the file contents.

Comment: pathlib.Path is usually always much nicer to work with than the `os` functions.